# Wondering do i have a mem leak(reported as potential)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create a NSMutableString called mutableScoreHolder outside my do-while loop.
I alloc it, 'copy' it into an other object called a 'Match' that contains a NSString.

When I build and analyze the  code it reports a potential memory leak of my mutableScoreHolder.

```
NSString * scoreHolder;
NSMutableString * mutableScoreHolder;
count = 1;
numMatchCounter = 0;
int startOfScoreIndex = 0; 
int endOfScoreIndex = 0;
int numberOfGoals=0;
do  
{
    match = [substring rangeOfString: @"points_bg"];

    if (match.location == NSNotFound) 
    {
        break;
    }
    if  ((match.location + match.length) > ([substring length]))
    {
        break;
    }

    substring = [substring substringFromIndex:(match.location + match.length)];

    match2 = [substring rangeOfString: @">"];   
    startOfScoreIndex = match2.location+1;

    match2 = [substring rangeOfString: @"<"];
    endOfScoreIndex = match2.location;

    if ((count % 2) == 1)
    {
        scoreHolder = [substring substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startOfScoreIndex, (endOfScoreIndex-startOfScoreIndex))];
        mutableScoreHolder = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:scoreHolder];
        numberOfGoals += [scoreHolder intValue];
    }
    else 
    {
        Match *aMatch = [theMatchScoresArray objectAtIndex:(numMatchCounter)];
        numberOfGoals += [[substring substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startOfScoreIndex, (endOfScoreIndex-startOfScoreIndex))] intValue];
        [scoreHolder stringByAppendingString:@" - "];
        [mutableScoreHolder appendString:@" - "];
        [scoreHolder stringByAppendingString:[substring substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startOfScoreIndex, (endOfScoreIndex-startOfScoreIndex))]];
        [mutableScoreHolder appendString:[substring substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startOfScoreIndex, (endOfScoreIndex-startOfScoreIndex))]];

        aMatch.theScore = [mutableScoreHolder copy];
        aMatch.matchGoalCount = numberOfGoals;
        numMatchCounter++;
        numberOfGoals=0;

    }   
    count++;
}
while ( match.length != 0 );
```

Here is my Match Object Class.

```
@interface Match : NSObject 
{
NSString *teamName1;
NSString *teamName2;
NSString *theScore;
int matchGoalCount;
NSMutableArray *scorersArray;
NSMutableArray *scorerOrderArray;
NSString *matchStatus;
NSString *matchDate;
bool matchNotStarted;
}   
@property(nonatomic) int matchGoalCount;
@property(nonatomic) bool matchNotStarted;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *teamName1;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *teamName2;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *theScore;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *matchStatus;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *matchDate;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *scorersArray;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *scorerOrderArray;

-(id)init;
@end

#import "Match.h"


@implementation Match
@synthesize teamName1;
@synthesize teamName2;
@synthesize theScore;
@synthesize scorersArray;
@synthesize matchDate;
@synthesize matchStatus;
@synthesize matchGoalCount;
@synthesize scorerOrderArray;
@synthesize matchNotStarted;


-(id)init
{
//NSLog(@"****** MATCH INIT ******");
self = [super init];
scorersArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
scorerOrderArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
return self;    
}

-(void) dealloc
{
[scorersArray release];
[scorerOrderArray release];
[teamName1 release];
[teamName2 release];
[theScore release];
[matchStatus release];
[matchDate release];
[scorersArray release];
[scorerOrderArray release];
[super dealloc];    
}
@end
```

I do find there there is a string leaked when i run instruments checking for leaks. So I think this 'potential leak' might be the leak I see.

Because the scores has a retain

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *theScore;
```

And there is a string copied into it

```
aMatch.theScore = [mutableScoreHolder copy];
```

Could that give a retain count of 2? And so then leak?

Sorry for the complicated question! Has my head spinning trying to get my head around it.

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're definitely leaking here, for 2 separate reasons.

The first is you're alloc/init'ing an NSMutableString and stuffing it into `mutableScoreHolder`. This is a local variable, and as soon as this value goes out of scope (or gets replaced the next time a new array is created) the old value is leaked. This should be an autoreleased value instead, as in `[NSMutableString stringWithString:scoreHolder]`.

The second is you're copying the string and stuffing the resulting value into a property. What you should do is redeclare that property as copy

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *theScore;
```

and then just assign `mutableScoreHolder` to that property directly

```
aMatch.theScore = mutableScoreHolder
```

With your existing code, you copy the array, and then the property retains it. With this change, the property copies it directly, and no extra retains are used.

Note, in general it's a good idea to declare properties with supported types as `copy`. This includes things like NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, etc. If you're assigning an already-immutable object to the property, the `copy` falls back to `retain` instead and there's no performance hit. But in situations like yours where you're assigning mutable objects, it will copy it as appropriate and keep an immutable snapshot in the property.

Comment: Hi Kevin, so it would be safe to change all my NSString and NSMutableArray that I have in match from 'retain' to 'copy' and it will be a bit safer? I've changed theScore already and it is working well. Thanks

Comment: If you have a property where the type is an immutable class that has a mutable variant (e.g. NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, etc.) it tends to be a good idea to use `copy`. This requires the type to support NSCopying, but all of the Cocoa classes that look like this do support copying.

Answer (score 0):

> And there is a string copied into it
>
> ```
> aMatch.theScore = [mutableScoreHolder copy];
> ```
>
> Could that
>   give a retain count of 2? And so then
>   leak?

exactly. You could change the property of `theScore` from `retain` to `copy` to fix this. THen you can use `aMatch.theScore = mutableScoreHolder;`

and there is (at least) one other leak:

```
mutableScoreHolder = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:scoreHolder];
```

this gets never released.